# MongoDB - running queries from a file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on a project, comparing times of processing queries with and without caching on different DB systems. Now I am using nodeJS and mongodb.

I have a txt file with queries (or more like conditions) that looks like this:

```
{'c1' : { $regex: /^A/ }, 'c2' : 'something', 'c3' : '8'}
{'c1' : { $regex: /^B/ }, 'c2' : 'somethingElse', 'c3' : '12'}
{'c1' : { $regex: /^C/ }, 'c2' : 'somethingDifferent', 'c3' : '16'}
...
```

And I need to read all these strings/objects from the file, make a query from each one of them and run them on the database (and measure the time it takes to finish all of these queries).

So my idea is to read the file line by line using a lineReader and convert the line to a query immediately, e.g.:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    query = line;
    //I only get this output
    console.log(query);

    query = JSON.stringify(query);
    dbo.collection('myCol').find(JSON.parse(query)).toArray(function(err, result) {
        //This code is never reached
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
}

db.close();
```

But this approach is wrong, because I never get any result from `find(query).toArray()` and the program crashes with

> MongoError: pool destroyed

every time.

I tried several different solutions, but I always ended up with this error or with `MongoNetworkError: connection destroyed, not possible to instantiate cursor`, or even the process running out of memory.

EDIT: JSON parsing

Comment: You're using line reader and reading text file line by line so for each line, you'll get STRING of object and MongoDB's find function takes object not string having object

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I changed my code to parse JSON from the string, however the problem remains. No results are printed and I still get `MongoError: pool destroyed` error.

Answer (score 1):

`MongoNetworkError: connection destroyed` error is only thrown by MongoDB in case of untimely `closing` of connection, assuming that the file is really huge, MongoDB queries are `async` in nature so, connection gets interrupted before `query` finishes. Try removing `db.close()` **(for testing, development purpose)** and find a way to close your connection safely after query is ran. **(before production release)**

**EDIT**

Run your server with this flag `--max-old-space-size=4096`

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js
```

Your Server is utilizing `memory` more than default defined by `v8 engine` which is around `1.7 GB`.

Comment: When I remove `db.close()`, my program freezes, still not getting any results from any of my queries. Then after a few seconds, I get `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. Could it be a sign of something being wrong with my queries execution? (I can post the whole stack trace if needed).

Comment: Check out the edit and Can you tell me  the size of your file?

Comment: Running my server with this flag caused the proccess to utilize more and more memory, up to about 5 GB, also utilizing my PC resources to the maximum, so I killed it. It didn't crash by it self though, like it did before. My file size (the one with queries) is 64 kB - 500 rows total. I set it up just for testing, I would like to use a file 10 times this size in future.

Answer (score 1):

When you run lineReader like that, you have no backpressure, meaning it will read all lines and fire everything to mongo.

Three options that come to mind are:

1. You want backpressure, to control the data passing operations to mongo. For example, using [Async Iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const stream = require('stream');

function readLines({ input }) {
  const output = new stream.PassThrough({ objectMode: true });
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input });
  rl.on("line", line => { 
    output.write(line);
  });
  rl.on("close", () => {
    output.push(null);
  }); 
  return output;
}
const input = fs.createReadStream("./pathToFile");
(async () => {
  for await (const line of readLines({ input })) {
    // mongo interaction that await each operation here
  }
})();
```

2. Accumulate and send a batch to mongo, either with `$in` operator like

```
{ $regex: $in:[/^A/, /^B/, /^C/] }
...
```

3. Accumulate each promise and when finished sending lines, use Bluebirds promise map to control concurrency.
   For example:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.txt')
});
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

var promises = [];

lineReader.on('line', function (query) {
    promises.push(query)
}

bluebird
.map(promises, 
  query => dbo.collection('myCol').find(query),
  { concurrency: 50 })
.then(...)
.catch(...)

db.close();
```